# Data type for IP address column in Big query

Tags: google-bigquery

Am new to big query. I need to know data type is used for IP Address column in Big query. Please let me know how to proceed

Comment: Please share a reproducible code example and what all you have tried so far.

Comment: You can store it however you like, personally I would choose `STRING`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the [String](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#string-type) type as BigQuery doesn't have a dedicated IP Address data type.